# Assign the value in the next row if condition met and leave other values the same

Tags: r, data-wrangling

This is the data that I have

```
       structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), columnA = c("2011/01/01", 
"2013/01/01", "2014/01/01", "2015/01/01", "2015/01/10"), columnB = c("NA", 
"2013/01/01", "2013/01/02", "2014/01/01", "NA")), row.names = c(NA, 
5L), class = "data.frame")
```

and this is what I want

```
  structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), A = c("2011/01/01", "2013/01/01", 
"2014/01/01", "2015/01/01", "2015/01/10"), B = c("NA", "2013/01/02", 
"NA", "2014/01/01", "NA")), row.names = c(NA, 5L), class = "data.frame")
```

Basically, i want if the values in columnA and columnB are equal, then bring up the value from row -1 in the same column and insert an NA in place of the value going up the column.
I tried this

```
`library(dplyr)
data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(columnB = case_when(is.na(columnB) ~ NA_character_,
                             columnA == columnB ~ lead(columnB))) %>%
  ungroup

`
```

the problem is that it convert all other values in columnB to NA as well. I want where the values in A and B are not equal to remain the same and not converted to NAs.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(columnB = case_when(columnA == columnB ~ lead(columnB),
                             lag(columnA) == lag(columnB) ~ NA_character_,
                             T ~ columnB))
```

**Output**

```
  id    columnA    columnB
1  1 2011/01/01         NA
2  1 2013/01/01 2013/01/02
3  1 2014/01/01       <NA>
4  1 2015/01/01 2014/01/01
5  1 2015/01/10         NA
```

Comment: Excellent! it worked perfectly. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome. If this answered your question please consider marking it as answered/upvoting.